# What's the pros and cons of disabling the swap partition if the RAM is large enough?

Tags: linux, partition, performance, swap

My computer has 16GB RAM and 1TB SSD. So I think the swap partition is not really needed.

What's the pros and cons of disabling the swap partition if the RAM is large enough?

Is it recommended to disable the swap partition in such a case?

Comment: This is *not* the same question as the one referenced as a duplicate. This question is about not *having* a swap partition. This is an install time question. The other question is about why the swap partition gets used *at runtime* even though there's free ram.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your application, doesn't it? I think you should have some swap space, perhaps even as small as half the RAM size. You don't want your system to choke.